# How to properly import files with static and dynamic classes?

Tags: python, oop, import

I've a main file (main.py):

```
execfile("library.py")

#import library : DOESN'T WORK

class c_config(object):

    static_var=3

print(c_config.static_var) # Works both ways

obj=another()

print(obj.dynamic) # Works with execfile and doesn't work with import
```

and a file of my library with my funcs and classes and so on (library.py):

```
class another(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.dynamic=c_config.static_var+1.3
```

I would like to import my library file with

```
import library
```

**which causes my imported object "another()" to not see the config class "c_config" with static_var, even though I imported it into this file with the config class...**

The execfile does it (not sure why). I'd like to construct it so that I use import.

Why can the object "obj=another()" not access the class "c_config" in the file it's been imported into?

Comment: What is the full traceback of the error you get? Also what is the folder structure, where are your files located relative to each other?

Comment: Remove the `.py` when importing modules in python.

Comment: I wrote the extension ".py" by mistake as I was editing. This has nothing to do with my problem. My test script has only the file name without extension of course.

Comment: The error with "import" is:

global name 'c_config' is not defined

But it doesn't occur with execfile()

Answer (score 3):

The most likely problem is that you are saying

```
from test_bib.py import *
```

when you should be using:

```
from test_bib import *
```

Imports don't need the `.py` extension - in fact it raises an `ImportError`.

This also goes for `library.py`. As you can run it with `execfile` it seems that the `library.py` file is in the same directory as your `main.py`. In which case you should also be able to do the following:

```
import library
```

In that case your `another` class can be accessed by:

```
obj = library.another()
```

EDIT:

So looking at your latest edit it looks like `c_config` is meant to be used in `library.py`, whereas it is defined in `main.py`.

This wouldn't work with `import library` in `main` as you need to have imported `c_config` into `library.py`. But importing `main` would create a circular import. It's generally best to keep interdependent classes in the same file.

Not sure why `execfile` is working,  unless it is silently failing. But I'm not at my computer right now so will research once I am.

Comment: I wrote the extension ".py" by mistake as I was editing. This has nothing to do with my problem. My test script has only the file name without extension of course.

Comment: Sorry, I was a little tired last night, so I messed up translating the file names into english. Now they are correct as I have them in the script. Allthough the problem has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Well I suppose the execfile() is a function like "include()" in PHP. This does nothing else but "paste" the file into the script you call it.

Once I had my libraries and config in the same file. I wanted to split them (by my PHP logic) and got this issues. So the script works within one file.

Answer (score 0):

The real issue is that you have a circular import; to get around this problem - simply call your `another()` object with the static variable as a parameter:

```
import library

class SomeObject(object):
    static_var = 3

obj = library.Another(SomeObject.static_var)
```

In `library.py`:

```
class Another(object):
    def __init__(self, static_var):
        self.dynamic_var = static_var + 1.3
```

> I already defined a class and want my imported functions to access it

Functions are different than methods.

A class creates its own namespace (it has its own scope) and you cannot access the outer scope from within the function.

Keep in mind when you import a module, the module contents are executed. It is already trying to refer to an object that doesn't exist; which is why it does not work.

Comment: I don't want to do this. I don't want to pass all configuration vars into the functions. I already defined a class and want my imported functions to access it

Comment: And why is my import circular?